# SSL Mail server connection times out on send()

Tags: ssh, email-server

When trying to programmatically send an email from a website of mine, with PHP Pear Mail package with SSL connection, PEAR:Mail replies the following :

```
Failed to connect to example.blabla.net:PORT
[SMTP: Failed to connect socket: connection timed out (code: -1, response: )]
```

I looked for similar questions on SO and SF, all the answers asking the OP to test a request on telnet or ssh in command line. So, that is what I did and here is what happens :

```
$ ssh -l myusername -p PORT example.blablabla.net
_
```

Here, '_' in the second line means that NOTHING happens. Indefinitely, which seems coherent with the timeout message I had from PEAR:Mail. So PEAR:Mail seems out of cause.

But, what I have to tell you is that **yesterday, it just worked**. Connection was properly established, mails were properly sent, etc. Just today, it doesn't work anymore and I absolutely don't know why. I restarted Apache (in case an extension was broken), restarted mail services, etc. Still. No effect.

Before yesterday (when it worked) and today (when it doesn't anymore), I just didn't touch the server and did nothing on it, simply because I took a day off to write some blog post!

Have anyone of you encountered similar problem ? The problem seems quite common, judging after some googling, but the solution doesn't.

Thanks for any help !

(note on config : CentOS 6.4 x86_64 with cPanel/WHM)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is connecting to a server controlled by someone else and delivering email to it (possibly sending email directly to the domain of the recipient?).  It isn't necessarily your fault that the connection doesn't go through; it actually sounds like a connectivity issue or the remote site being down intermittently.

To help work around this, you can usually direct all your mail to be related through your own SMTP server, which will be able to do things like hold it in a queue and retry.  As you are unfortunate enough to be using cPanel, this means you will have to use exim on localhost, or set up another server to relay email.  It's usually best to host such things on localhost if you can, as it greatly reduces the likelihood of a connect failure causing mail to get dropped.